# The difference between modifying the UI component color through Image.color and CanvasRenderer.SetColor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Normally, when we want to change the Color of the Image component, we can directly modify the Color property of the Image component. The principle is to modify the vertex color of the mesh. This operation has a certain cost, because it will cause the Canvas.BuildBatch operation.

I recently read some UGUI source codes, and I found that when the Button component is set to the Color Tint type, there will be a color gradient process when clicking, and a coroutine will be triggered at this time, each execution of the coroutine will modify the color of the CanvasRenderer component, instead of directly modifying the Color property of the Image component.

```cs
public abstract class Graphic : UIBehaviour, ICanvasElement
{
    private readonly TweenRunner<ColorTween> m_ColorTweenRunner;

    //trigger on click
    public virtual void CrossFadeColor(Color targetColor, float duration, 
        bool ignoreTimeScale, bool useAlpha, bool useRGB)
    {
        //...
        var colorTween = new ColorTween {duration = duration, 
            startColor = canvasRenderer.GetColor(), targetColor = targetColor};

        //The callback here will be triggered in the coroutine,
        //Modify the color of the canvasRenderer component
        colorTween.AddOnChangedCallback(canvasRenderer.SetColor);

        colorTween.ignoreTimeScale = ignoreTimeScale;
        colorTween.tweenMode = mode;

        //Start coroutine
        m_ColorTweenRunner.StartTween(colorTween);
    }
}
```

What I don't quite understand is, what is the essential difference between these two ways of writing? Is it more efficient to modify CanvasRenderer.color directly?